# Invalid Outside Procedure when Using Search Button in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, button

I was working on a database for a small clubhouse to manage accounts. One form allowed users to search for a member's balance. After a user made cosmetic changes to the form, I am now receiving an invalid outside procedure error, and I am unable to figure out why.

The debugger is suggesting that the first line in my button code is to blame. The code for the search button in question is as follows:

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click()

Dim SQL As String

SQL = "SELECT [Member Balance Query].MemberName, [Member Balance Query].[Sum Of Actual Amount]" _
    & "FROM [Member Balance Query] " _
    & "WHERE MemberName LIKE '*" & Me.txtMemberName & "*'" _
    & "ORDER BY [Member Balance Query].[MemberName]"

Me.SubBalanceSearch.Form.RecordSource = SQL
Me.SubBalanceSearch.Form.Requery


End Sub
```

Any help figuring out what I may need to do to correct the error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add a space in SQL on new line `SQL = "SELECT [Member Balance Query].MemberName, [Member Balance Query].[Sum Of Actual Amount]" _
    & " FROM [Member Balance Query] " _
    & " WHERE MemberName LIKE '*" & Me.txtMemberName & "*'" _
    & " ORDER BY [Member Balance Query].[MemberName]"`

Comment: That error suggests that there are mismatched function delimiters or other code blocks, like `Private Sub ...` and `End Sub` or `If` and `End If`. Mismatched delimiters can sometimes cause incorrect debugger suggestions. How do you know that the change was only cosmetic?  Did they change the name of an object, so that it's corresponding event handlers are no longer valid?  Any other possible code change?  Beside manual inspection of the code, one extreme is to systematically remove all code and add each function or sub back into the module until you find which code block really has the error.

Comment: If users are causing form changes (and even when they don't), I suggest always keeping a development copy and never changing the "production" version of the database.  This implies that the database has separate frontend and backend files so that such an approach is manageable.  (Separating the data from the user interface and business logic.)  When a problem like this occurs, just replace the frontend with a fresh copy... and then follow up with the user about making permanent improvements to the development version of the form, etc.